# React setstate after map()

Tags: reactjs, loops, dictionary, state

I did a map() to loop through an array , and for each iteration in the loop i'm adding a value to my variable (var total= 0 initially), so in the end of the loop my total variable as a non null value. I want to assign this value to my state(totPrice). Here is my component:

```
class Items extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //console.log(props)
    var ob=props.items;
    var tot=0;
    ob.map((item) => {tot+=item.Cost});

    this.state={
        totPrice: tot,
        check: true
    }
}

handlePriceChange(cost){
    //console.log(event)
    this.setState({check:!this.state.check},function(){
        if(this.state.check== false){
            this.setState({totPrice:this.state.totPrice -=cost})
        }
        else{
            this.setState({totPrice:this.state.totPrice +=cost})
        }
    });

}
    render() {
        const obj=this.props.items;
        var total=0;



 return (
            <div className="container">
               <a href="/products">Continue shopping</a>
               {
                obj.map((item,i) => {
                    total+=item.Cost;
                    return <li key={i}><input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.check}  onChange={()=>this.handlePriceChange(item.Cost)}/> <span>{item.Name}</span>  <span>{item.Cost}</span></li>
                })

               }
                <h3>Total price:{this.state.totPrice}</h3>
            </div>
        );

    }
}
export default Items;
```

I've tried `this.setState({totPrice:total})` after the map() but this give me an error. Tried in the componentDidMount() , doesn't know the total variable. Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the total price in the constructor.
Change

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
        totPrice: 0,
        check: true
    }
}
```

to

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // calculate the total price here, using Javascript's Array reduce()
    this.state={
        totPrice: 0,
        check: true
    }
}
```

then, call `handlePriceChange` with the index

```
return (
  <li key={i}>
    <input type="checkbox" 
      defaultChecked={this.state.check}
      onChange={ () => this.handlePriceChange.bind(this)(i) }
    />
    <span>{item.Name}
      </span>  <span>
    {item.Cost}</span>
  </li>
);
```

finally, in `handlePriceChange()` add or substract the item's price from the total price, based on the check value before changing it.

Comment: Worked fine . But why using bind(this). I thought in arrow functions we dont need to do that

Comment: One more thing please . Why passing i as paramter ? I've tried to passe item.cost so i can substract/add the cost if checkbox is checked or not . But that is not working correctly . How can i use the (i) passed to find the cost of à specific item ?

Comment: No reason. Actually i should have passed item... what do you get when you try to pass item.cost? Or item? Any error? Undefined?

Comment: No it works . The cost is passed correctly . But in the handlePriceChange() , when i set the check state to false , it changes it for every <li> , not the only one i unchecked . So after when i check it back i have Problem to add/substract the correct price. I will post my code so you can what im talking about

Comment: sorry not, when i check it back. when i uncheck another <li>

Comment: You need to define an array of check values in your state, a value per each item, not just a single value...

Comment: Also change if(this.state.check== false) to if(!this.state.check). Doesn't do any harm, just cleaner

Comment: Worked fine now . That really helped me a lot. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am very glad!